# Error code 30000, SQL state 42X02: Lexical error at line 1, column 8. Encountered: "`" (96), after: ". Line 1, column 1

Tags: mysql, view, javadb

I tried creating a view in Java DB, but I keep getting this error.

```
Error code 30000, SQL state 42X02: Lexical error at line 1, column 8.
Encountered: "`" (96), after : "". Line 1, column 1
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM memberdetails m 
JOIN attendance a 
JOIN meeting mm 
WHERE a.memberid=m.memdetailsid AND a.meetingid=mm.meid;
```

In MySQL I don't get any error with this code.Any help will be appreciated